# How to get the element name of a deeper lying element in XML with Golang

Tags: xml, go

I got the following XML structure

XML-structure:

```
<assay>
    <step id="1">
        <command>
            <bar>
                <ab>structure 1</ab>
            </bar>
            <duration>5</duration>
        </command>
    </step>
    <step id="2">
        <command>
            <bar>
                <cd>structure 2</cd>
            </bar>
            <duration>5</duration>
        </command>
    </step>
    <step id="3">
        <command>
            <bar>
                <de>structure 3</de>
            </bar>
            <duration>5</duration>
        </command>
    </step>
    <step id="4">
        <command>
            <bar>
                <ab>structure 1</ab>
            </bar>
            <duration>5</duration>
        </command>
    </step>
</assay>
```

and created the following struct in golang

```
type Assay struct {
    Steps []struct {
        ID           int     `xml:"id"`
        Duration     int     `xml:"duration"`
        Instruction  string  `xml:"command>bar"`
        Command      Command `xml:"command"`
    } `xml:"step"`
}

type Command struct {
    Bar    struct {
        Ab *Ab struct {}  `xml:"ab"`
        Cd *Cd struct {}  `xml:"cd"`
        De *De struct {}  `xml:"de"`
    } `xml:bar`
}
```

Is it possible to write in the Instruction field the element name from the elements in the bar element (ab, cd, de)? I get the element name with xml.Name but i got this only inside the ab, cd, ef struct.

The other question: is it possible tha inside the Bar struct only the struct from the XML is shown?

At the moment it looks like:

```
Bar {
    Ab: {...some Informations}
    Cd: {nil}
    De:{nil}
}
Bar {
    Ab: {nil}
    Cd: {...some Informations}
    De:{nil}
}
```

It should be:

```
Bar {
    Ab: {...some Informations}
}
Bar {
    Cd: {...some Informations}
}
```

I receive the XMl as a string and unmarshal it with the following code:

```
func ExtractAssay(stringXML string) (structXML requests.Assay) {
    stringByte := []byte(stringXML)
    err := xml.Unmarshal(stringByte, &structXML)
    if nil != err {
        fmt.Println("Error unmarshalling from XML", err)
        return
    }
    return structXML
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried to unmarshal the xml into given structs

Answer (score 0):

The following snipet provide complete decoding XML struct, 
If you do not want include ab, cd, and de type while encoding to XML just add ommitempty to xml tag.

```
var XML = `<assay>
    <step id="1">
        <command>
            <bar>
                <ab>structure 1</ab>
            </bar>
            <duration>5</duration>
        </command>
    </step>
    <step id="2">
        <command>
            <bar>
                <cd>structure 2</cd>
            </bar>
            <duration>5</duration>
        </command>
    </step>
    <step id="3">
        <command>
            <bar>
                <de>structure 3</de>
            </bar>
            <duration>5</duration>
        </command>
    </step>
    <step id="4">
        <command>
            <bar>
                <ab>structure 1</ab>
            </bar>
            <duration>5</duration>
        </command>
    </step>
</assay>`



type Assay struct {
    Steps []struct {
        ID           int     `xml:"id"`
        Duration     int     `xml:"duration"`
        Command      Command `xml:"command"`
    } `xml:"step"`
}

type Ab struct {
    Value string `xml:",chardata"`
}
type Cd struct {
    Value string `xml:",chardata"`
}
type De struct {
    Value string `xml:",chardata"`
}
type Bar struct {
    Ab *Ab  `xml:"ab,omitempty"`
    Cd *Cd  `xml:"cd,omitempty"`
    De *De `xml:"de,omitempty"`
}

type Command struct {
    Bar  *Bar `xml:"bar"`
}




func main() {

    var asSay = &Assay{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(XML), &asSay)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for _, step := range asSay.Steps {
        if step.Command.Bar != nil {
            if step.Command.Bar.Ab != nil {
                fmt.Printf("ab: %v\n", step.Command.Bar.Ab)
            }
            if step.Command.Bar.Cd != nil {
                fmt.Printf("cd: %v\n", step.Command.Bar.Cd)
            }
            if step.Command.Bar.De != nil {
                fmt.Printf("de: %v\n", step.Command.Bar.De)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. The "omitempty" tag is only used for creating XML i think. With your example i also get the struct i described in my question with the nil elements.